# Implementing a custom authentication schema with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm new to this area of web development, and since I've been programming with C# for a while, I decided to give a try to ASP.NET.

Everything seemed so easy and good to work with! The routes, the controllers, the views (Razor view engine is so fantastic)...until I came across with authentication.

There are a lot of tutorials (and the documentation) out there about Identity, saying it's amazing and how decoupled it is, how extensible it is, but I still feel like it's a black box.

I struggled so much trying to make a super simple authentication system using a simple table with a few columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    [Email] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Password] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

All I wanted to do was create a system where the user would enter his email and password and I'd show a simple message "Welcome [firstname]!".

But this seems to be so much complicated to do with ASP.NET Identity. Everyone (including the documentation itself) is using and abusing Entity Framework and SQL Server, using built-in models like IdentityDbContext where you get lots of tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc) and columns, which don't have any use or meaning for my purposes and that's it! I feel like the whole community is doing this (same models, same database schema, same everything) and they're happy with it.

With all this glamour of being extensible and decoupled, **am I really able to extend the ASP.NET Identity and build a simple login and signup system? Am I really able to do what I want?**

Or I'm forced to use IdentityDbContext, and use all those tables and columns, use EntityFramework and SQL Server, roles, claims, two-factor authentication? (because of [maybe] security standards).

Don't get me wrong, I'm just trying to understand this system but It looks so complex and I feel like I'm locked with this rules (and if I'm really forced to use all this, why is it like that? Is it because of security standards?).

Comment: You can create  custom application user class to cover fields you want to have in your desired system. you are not forced t use roles or claims.

Comment: It does it out of the box. Just create a new MVC project and use "Individual Accounts" option. Authorisation/authentication is a complex problem and there is no "simple" solution. It is as simple as you can get out of the box. Anything you will do will only make the matter more complex.